# IUPAC name for compound with various carbonyl groups

Tags: nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

I found this question on a resource video for IUPAC Nomenclature for a competitive exam. It would be great if someone provided the approved IUPAC approved name for this compound. Source of the question : https://youtu.be/SpUoxVq-hmI?t=432
[image: Bond Line Structure of the Compound]

As per the IUPAC Nomenclature or what I understood from it, it is given that whenever the carbon atom is not counted we need to use different prefixes. In this case that would mean the substituent with the locant number 4 should be named as methoxycarbonyl and the substituent on the locant number 3, chlorocarbonyl. So as per that, I wrote the answer as 3-chlorocarbonyl-6-formyl-4-methoxycarbonyl-8-oxy nonanoic acid but I don't think that it is right. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The carbonyl on carbon 8 is called 8-oxo.

Comment: Oh yah i typed it as oxy..... so other than that is the naming of the compound right @MathewMahindaratne ?

Comment: @CalistoMathias You might want to check the rules for parentheses. Also note that there is a wrong space in the suggested name.